# AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'title_count' error in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Below is my models.py in Django 1.9.7. Executing from the python manage.py shell the following `Book.object.title_count('book')`, produces this error
`AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'title_count'`.

Isn't it defined in the BookManager?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def title_count(self, keyword):
        return self.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    num_pages = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    objects = BookManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean object**s**:

```
Book.objects.title_count('book')
           ^
```